# .NET Framework 4.7.2 stuck on installation and roll back on Windows Server 2016

Tags: installation, windows-server-2016, .net, dotnet-framework

When trying to install the .NET Framework version 4.7.2, it gets stuck on the installation and freezes here:

[image]

I waited for over an hour for the .NET Framework to install, and it stayed at the same spot. I attempted to cancel the installation, and it's stuck on rolling back the installation as well:

[image]

Is there anything I need to change on the OS to be able to install the .NET Framework? I'm not sure why it's stuck on this spot, and any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the issue appear with the offline bundle too, and what the setup log show ?

Comment: I haven't tried the offline bundle. I cancelled the installation and unfortunately it doesn't show as installed in Programs and Features, but I can't attempt a reinstallation because it says it is already installed. I'm not sure why this is, so I'll do some digging to try and fix it.

Comment: I reinstalled Windows 10, then attempted to install .NET Framework 4.7.2 with the offline installer. It worked perfectly. I'm not sure why the online installer errored out, but if you want to post the answer to the issue as using the offline installer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would give a try with the [offline](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=863265) bundle. It often resolve strange issue that the online's bundle can have.

If the first step don't work, you can see the MSI error log too, which can give some hints.

Comment: the same problem with 4.8 :( I'm trying offline installer but I had to restart the server to make installation progress to move

Answer (score 2):

In my experience and across many .Net releases, very often the issue is that the .Net installer setup wants to launch the Windows Installer service, and if for any reason that fails to start it will sit there forever waiting. Manually starting the installer service via Admin Tools / Services will kick the progress back into life.

Comment: This resolved the issue for me!